# Q:How to read the new window Web Browser Console in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to get the new windows web console message.
But use as below that will print first windows console content.
How to get the new web console message?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

d = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
d['loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL' }
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('d:\code\chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=chrome_options,desired_capabilities=d)

driver.get('my_test_url')

#click the element will create a new windows
driver.find_element_by_id(a_element').click()

handles = driver.window_handles
#switch to new window
driver.switch_to_window(handles[1])

for entry in driver.get_log('browser'):
    print ('log')
    print(entry)
```

Comment: didn't get what exactly is your question

Comment: use as below, chrome will open and create windows.
`driver.get('my_test_url')`
But click this element and the browser will create new windows.
`driver.find_element_by_id(a_element').click()`

But I don't know how to read the new windows web console message.

I use `for entry in driver.get_log('browser'): print(entry)`
then still print the first windows web console message.

Answer (score 0):

try this code based on your code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

d = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
d['loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL' }
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('d:\code\chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=chrome_options,desired_capabilities=d)

driver.get('my_test_url')

#click the element will create a new windows
driver.find_element_by_id(a_element').click()

driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])


for entry in driver.get_log('browser'):
    print(entry)
```